# Jenkins + Sonar create project

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I'm having problem with the execution of sonar analysis from Jenkins jobs. I have Jenkins ver. 1.621 and sonar Version 5.1.

I had this tools working and executing sonar analysis from Jenkins til I define user authentication with LDAP in both applications. There is no error in the execution of jobs and I can see the execution of sonar command task in Jenkins project log but when I check sonar the analysis never happened. I just check "everything" but I don't know what could be, I thinking could be role/permissions but I checked this and it seem right.

Any idea about What could be happened?

These are my specification:

Jenkins

Project-Sonar. This is the content of "Analysis properties" defined in the Post Steps->Invoke StandAlone SonarQube Analysis.

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=plandecuentas
sonar.projectName=plandecuentas
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Set modules IDs
#sonar.modules=src
# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src
# Language
sonar.language=java
# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Jenkins-Sonar Library:
Sonar-Qube Plugin 2.2.1
I have configured this libraries with the same info before enable LDAP authentication.

Comment: Does 'Anyone' have analysis permissions on the project?

Comment: Hi, G. Ann. Now the tools are working perfectly, the problem was that the projects used an user that doesn't exist in LDAP. Now projects are using valid ldap user. Thanks for your comment.